# She will find out (if / that) he is telling the truth

Tags: word-choice, whether-if

She will find out (if / that) he is telling the truth.

I think the answer is 'if'. If so why not 'that'? 
What do you think is the correct answer? (I don't know which answer is correct)

[image]

Comment: It's a stupid test, because both ***if*** and ***that*** are perfectly valid alternatives in the first context, as are ***when*** and ***whether*** in the second example. Whereas the third and fourth examples are so trivial it's hard to imagine *anyone* getting them wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are possible, and have different meanings:

Situation 1.  John says "I caught a shark in the lake". I've seen the shark; I know that John is telling the truth.  Mary doesn't believe John. But tomorrow John will show Mary the picture of the shark

> She will find out tomorrow that he is telling the truth.

Situation 2.  John says "I caught a shark in the lake".  I haven't seen the shark; neither Mary not I know if he is telling the truth.  But tomorrow Mary will find out if John is lying.

> She will find out tomorrow if he is telling the truth.

The test writer probably intended the second situation.  In speech the stress and intonation would be rather different between Situation 1 and 2

Likewise for Q2 both are possible (but whether is more likely in this context)

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence:

> 1. She will find out (if / that) he is telling the truth.

both "if" and "that" are correct, but the meaning is different. With "if", the implication is that he may or may not be telling the truth, while with "that" it is a fact that he is telling the truth, as she will find out.

Both linkers are also possible in (2): with "whether", it is unknown if it will snow or not; with "when", it is known it will snow tomorrow -- what is not known is what time it will snow (in the morning, afternoon, or evening).